# how to find the right repository

Tags: repository, workflow, snakemake

when I was reading the 'Workflow Distribution and Deployment' about snakemake, I found that I can't clone the working directory, because the link is wrong. After running the command, it promotes:
remote: Not Found
fatal: repository 'https://bitbucket.org/user/myworkflow.git/' not found

Comment: The link is referring to a toy example that should be replaced with your own repository path.

Comment: Thank you, it's helpful for me!